# Apache and nginx on a VMware environment - good idea? Static content delivery?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, web-server, virtual-machines

I'm considering using 2 virtual servers, 1 running Apache facing the internet (e.g. www.example.com) running over https and other running ngnix on a private ip connecting to the main server to serve static content e.g. /data (css, PDF's, etc).  The machines will both be hosted in a VM environment both running on the same network.

My questions is how feasible is this to set up and is it even feasible? Also is it a good idea to do it this way as I know nginx is better at serving static content  and as its on a different server then its scalable for performance and space.

Does this make sense or is a good idea?

Comment: It is very possible that you will not see a performance difference between the 2 :)  It all depends on how you configure your apache/nginx...  In the end, I think virtualizing is a great idea.

Comment: email me, vasiliy@clustermagnet.com if you need help setting this up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is feasible to setup but you would be better having nginx on the public facing server,  even if you have apache on this also have nginx first which proxys to apache and you can then proxy to the one with the private ip for the static content.

Comment: Would it be best to have apache then proxy to nginx?